# Derivative of a squared distance function with respect to a finite set

Tags: calculus, derivatives, projection

I have the following question: Let $ Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ denote a finite set. Then, let us consider the squared distance function $ F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,\infty) $ defined by $ F(x)=\min_{y \in Y} ||x-y||_2^2 $.

Is $ F $ differentiable?

I mean, there are similar theorems, but all I found involve convexity of the set $ Y $, which is of course not given here. Normally, this convexity is then used to have a unique projection, an argument we cannot use for finite $ Y $.

So, how could a proof work in this setting?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: try graphing an example in one dimension. If $F$ was differentiable in two dimensions, it would necessarily have one-dimensional analogues differentiable as well.

Comment: First of all: I forgot to mention that $ Y $ is non-empty. Sorry. Just to avoid degenerate cases. However, I already thought about it from an illustrative point of view, but I had the hope that the squaring of the distance possibly helps to ensure at least partial differentiability.

Comment: Nope. Try graphing $ \min\left(\left(x+1\right)^{2},\left(x-1\right)^{2}\right)$